# Possible reasons for 500 internal server error in ajax call using aspx and c#

Tags: ajax, post, fullcalendar, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

i am making an ajax call to fetch event for rendering a fullcalendar.

- i am using a webmethod written in c#.
- the ajax call is being made    from an aspx page.
- my site is a sharepoint 2010 site.
- the calendar is being rendered using fullcalendar.js

i am facing the below issue :

the calendar works perfectly in most of the browsers and machines. but in some machine it doesn't render the events and when i look into the developer tool of the browser. it show me a

> 500 internal server error

in my ajax post call status.

can anyone tell me that what are the possible reasons for this error.

below is my call syntax along with the webmethod.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'PublicCauseList.aspx/GetCalendarItems',
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {

                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log("Error in fetching calendar events.");
                }
            });



[WebMethod]
        public static string GetCalendarItems(string courtSelected, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            }
```

thanks

Comment: Error 500 is internal server error. Probably an exception or error has occured on server.

Comment: For me it happened if you're sending requests too frequently, e.g. more than 4 requests per second.

Comment: but at a same moment of time. how can it happen that on one machine it works perfect and on other it doesnt work at all. with same user credentials and browser version